# dynamic_cast on a vector of objects c++

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-cast

I have this code:

```
//set the AppSystem's Application Vector
void AppSystem::setAppVector(vector<Application *> &applicationVector){
   try{
       vector<Application *> &tmp1();
       tmp1 = dynamic_cast<vector<Application *>>(applicationVector);
       if ((tmp1 == NULL) || (applicationVector == NULL)) throw new MyExceptions();
       this->ClearAppVector();
       this->AppVector = applicationVector;
   }catch(MyExceptions e){
       return e.ObjectVectorException();
   }
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
AppSystem.cpp:23:69: error: cannot dynamic_cast 'applicationVector' (of type 'class std::vector<Application*>') to type 'class std::vector<Application*>' (target is not pointer or reference)
         tmp1 = dynamic_cast<vector<Application *>>(applicationVector);
```

but the target is a reference of type `vector<Application*>`. Any suggestion?

Comment: A vector is not a pointer. Why do you expect to be able to `dynamic_cast` it?

Comment: How can I cast a vector?

Comment: You cannot. I think you misunderstand what casts do.

Comment: So I have to pass all the elements of vector to see if they are Application * type?

Comment: @konstantinosDms `throw new MyExceptions()` -- `catch(MyExceptions e)` -- A word of advice -- C++ is not Java.  Exceptions are thrown by reference, not by value, and `new` in C++ is not the same as `new` in Java.  Second, what exactly are you trying to accomplish, on a high-level?  Your issue sounds more like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  But in general, your code looks like an attempt of writing C++ code using Java as a model.  That will *never* work out -- the code will either be buggy, have memory leaks, be inefficient, or just look plain weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: Yes you are right, I come from Java and c# programming languages, and I have many things to do for my master on c++. I want to cast a vector<Application *> object with this within the parameter of the method.

Comment: C++ cannot be learned by using Java and/or C# as a model in writing C++ code -- your code is a classic example of these ill-fated attempts.  First, a `vector<Application *>` is just that -- a vector that contains pointers to an `Application`, nothing more, nothing less.  Casting doesn't do any tricks or conversions of the internal type -- you passed a `vector<Application *>`, then that's what it is.  Second, `new` requires you to deallocate the memory, else you have memory leaks.

Comment: Also, looking at that entire function -- it just isn't C++, and that is trying to be honest with you.  It does really look like you had an idea about how to do this in Java (or C#) and tried to do a translation to C++.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<Application *> &tmp1();` is not a declaration of a **variable** named `tmp1` of type `vector<Application*>&`. It is a declaration of a **function** named `tmp1` that returns a `vector<Application*>&`. Even if it were a variable, you can't declare an uninitialized reference.

As for the error message itself, it is self-explanatory if you actually read it:

> target is not pointer or reference

You are passing in a *reference* to a `vector` object (that is OK) and trying to cast it to a non-reference type (that is not OK). `vector<Application*>` is not a reference type. `vector<Application*>&` is a reference type.

You don't need the `dynamic_cast` at all. You are trying to cast a reference to a `vector<Application*>` into a `vector<Application*>`, which is redundant. And since a reference can't be NULL, and a cast of a reference can't return a NULL pointer, your exception handling is unnecessary, too:

```cpp
//set the AppSystem's Application Vector
void AppSystem::setAppVector(vector<Application *> &applicationVector)
{
    this->ClearAppVector();
    this->AppVector = applicationVector;
}
```